# access static values in a Stimulus Typescript controller with the default settings from Symfony

Tags: typescript, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore, stimulusjs

I'm trying to learn Stimulus with a more or less default install of Symfony6 and Encore, one of the main differences with the default install being that I'm using Typescript.
The [Stimulus docs say that typed values should be used like so](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/managing-state#using-values) =>

```js
export default class extends Controller {
  static values = { index: Number }

  initialize() {
    console.log(this.indexValue)
    console.log(typeof this.indexValue)
  }

  // …
}
```

However when using Typescript, I get a  `TS2339: Property 'indexValue' does not exist on type 'default'.` on accessing `this.indexValue`; I managed to get away with this with a `@ts-ignore` but I think that sucks. Do you know of any cleaner way to handle this in a webpack Encore Symfony project ? Thanks in advance

My Stimulus controller =>

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

default class extends Controller {
    static values = {
        index: Number
    }

    doSomethingAsync(event: Event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // @ts-ignore
        console.log("indexValue", this.indexValue);
    }
}
```

My tsconfig =>

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "sourceMap": true,

    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

my `webpack.config.js` =>

```js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
  Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
  // directory where compiled assets will be stored
  .setOutputPath('public/build/')
  // public path used by the web server to access the output path
  .setPublicPath('/build')
  // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
  //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

  /*
   * ENTRY CONFIG
   *
   * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.ts)
   * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
   */
  .addEntry('app', './assets/app.ts')

  // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.ts)
  .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

  // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
  .splitEntryChunks()

  // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
  // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
  .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

  /*
   * FEATURE CONFIG
   *
   * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
   * list of features, see:
   * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
   */
  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableBuildNotifications()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
  .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

  .configureBabel((config) => {
    config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
  })

  // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
  .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
    config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
    config.corejs = 3;
  })

  // enables Sass/SCSS support
  .enableSassLoader()

  // uncomment if you use TypeScript
  .enableTypeScriptLoader()

// uncomment if you use React
//.enableReactPreset()

// uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
// requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
//.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

// uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
//.autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

my `package.json` =>

```json
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fontsource/roboto-condensed": "^4.5.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.0.0",
    "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^3.0.0",
    "@symfony/stimulus-bridge-types": "^1.0.0",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^2.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "sass": "^1.52.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch",
    "build": "encore production --progress"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "defaults",
    "not IE 11"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript support in Stimulus still has a few rough edges, however here is a solution that many users have found works for them.

First set up an Abstract class that holds the generic typing and an ignore comment.

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

export default abstract class AbstractController<StimulusElement extends Element> extends Controller {
    // @ts-ignore see https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/stimulus-and-typescript/2458
    declare readonly element: StimulusElement;
}
```

Then in your controller, extend the abstract one and some things will be easier, you still need to declare individual usage of things like `indexValue`.

```js
import AbstractController from '../src/AbstractController';

export default class extends AbstractController<HTMLButtonElement> {
    static values = {
        index: Number,
    };

    static targets = [
        'name'
    ];

    declare readonly indexValue: number
    declare readonly nameTarget: HTMLInputElement
}
```

https://discuss.hotwired.dev/t/stimulus-and-typescript/2458/2

### additional links

- PR to bring better Typescript support in a future release https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/pull/529
- PR with docs on using Typescript for the future release https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/pull/540/files
- issue relating to Typescript https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/issues/457

Comment: what is nameTarget? I see it referenced [in the official docs](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/), but I don't see it [defined in Controller](https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus/blob/8a614c5f72b84c0a022172397b40bcd4348582e0/src/core/controller.ts#L19).

Comment: nameTarget is just an example target, each target will be based on the static targets value.